# Delete certain records from an index in elastic but not all

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a requirement to delete all the URLs (which are broken/404) at an index. The number of URLs are more than 3k. I can delete an individual URL (which is not feasible) but never used bulk api of elastic, so not sure how to write a query for this.
Need help for this.

I tried writing a bulk query for the purpose but that doesn't work.

Comment: Is the URL stored in a keyword field of your document ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [delete_By_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) API call to remove some documents in index/indices.

```
POST /test_delete_by_query/_bulk
{"index":{"_id": "1"}}
{"status_code": "200"}
{"index":{"_id": "2"}}
{"status_code": "201"}
{"index":{"_id": "3"}}
{"status_code": "404"}
{"index":{"_id": "4"}}
{"status_code": "404"}
{"index":{"_id": "5"}}
{"status_code": "502"}
```

---

```
GET test_delete_by_query/_count
```

---

```
GET test_delete_by_query/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status_code": "404"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST test_delete_by_query/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status_code": "404"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
GET test_delete_by_query/_count
```

[image]

Comment: the below query worked.

POST /cdf_prod_en/_delete_by_query { "query": { "terms": { "url": ["url1", "url2", "url3"] } } }

Comment: happy to hear it worked!